# How can i install plugin in gephi 0.9.1?

Tags: social-networking, gephi

I am new to gephi and I am trying to install plugin automatically but it seems it does not show available pluging on market place automatically. Even I clicked "check for newest" but it is showing nothing. I tried manually but it doesnot proceed a head and give me list of some requirement which I am not abe to understand. I am attaching image of it. Let me know how to proceed ahead. [image]

Comment: Can you tell us which plugin is it about? From what I see from your error the plugin you are trying to install is not available yet for Gephi 0.9.1. You could possibly try to install 0.8.1 and then the respective plugins. Lately, the automatic plugin installation doesn't work that well and you 'd better download the plugin from the marketplace first and then install